# Silverlight and WCF error

Tags: wcf, silverlight

I am working at silverlight application and my ask is about wcf and silverlight..
I crated silverlight app and wcf library in one solution..

Then linked service to app via Add service reference..

[image]

When I start only service, it's working without problem..
Problem just start when I want to run application.. I've got error about client access policy, which I have add as well..

**So my ask is:** Is there a way how to start app (and debug) and service together witout that error? and without duty to deploy? Only in debug mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `clientaccesspolicy.xml` and/or `crossdomain.xml` files are *not* required inside your client application, and they do *not* belong in your web service directory. Rather, they must be copied into the *root* of your web server. Mostly, that would be the directory `C:\inetpub\wwwroot` instead of `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\PDFService`.

Comment: Thank you for your response.. Is this possible too if I am developing at Windows 8.1? Not Windows Server?

Comment: You mean with "Windows 8.1" that you're debugging on your local machine? In that case, the cross-domain issue shouldn't come up at all. You'll have to be more specific about your error message then.

Comment: This is my error.. It's that same error
http://s14.postimg.org/8ers466r5/Capture.png

Comment: Use a tool like Fiddler to find out if and where Silverlight is looking for the XML files.

Comment: Thank you.. I will try Fiddler.. Can I later write here if some questions? thx :)